# Find object data duplicates in List of objects

Tags: c#, .net

Using c# 3 and .Net Framework 3.5, I have a Person object

```
public Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int SSN { get; set; }
}
```

and I've got a List of them:

```
List<Person> persons = GetPersons();
```

How can I get all the Person objects in persons where SSN is not unique in the list and remove them from the persons list and ideally add them to another list called "`List<Person> dupes`"?

The original list might look something like this:

```
persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(new Person { Id = 1, 
                         FirstName = "Chris", 
                         LastName="Columbus", 
                         SSN=111223333 }); // Is a dupe
persons.Add(new Person { Id = 1, 
                         FirstName = "E.E.", 
                         LastName="Cummings", 
                         SSN=987654321 });
persons.Add(new Person { Id = 1, 
                         FirstName = "John", 
                         LastName="Steinbeck", 
                         SSN=111223333 }); // Is a dupe
persons.Add(new Person { Id = 1, 
                         FirstName = "Yogi", 
                         LastName="Berra", 
                         SSN=123456789 });
```

And the end result would have Cummings and Berra in the original persons list and would have Columbus and Steinbeck in a list called dupes.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This gets you the duplicated SSN:

```
var duplicatedSSN =
    from p in persons
    group p by p.SSN into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g.Key;
```

The duplicated list would be like:

```
var duplicated = persons.FindAll( p => duplicatedSSN.Contains(p.SSN) );
```

And then just iterate over the duplicates and remove them.

```
duplicated.ForEach( dup => persons.Remove(dup) );
```

Comment: Your solution was close. The line `duplicated = persons.FindAll(duplicatedSSN.Contains(p => p.SSN);` did not work. See my answer to see what I corrected to get to the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to gcores for getting me started down a correct path. Here's what I ended up doing:

```
var duplicatedSSN =
    from p in persons
    group p by p.SSN into g
    where g.Count() > 1
    select g.Key;

var duplicates = new List<Person>();

foreach (var dupeSSN in duplicatedSSN)
{
    foreach (var person in persons.FindAll(p => p.SSN == dupeSSN))
        duplicates.Add(person);
}

duplicates.ForEach(dup => persons.Remove(dup));
```

Comment: Sorry, the line was wrong. It should have said duplicated = persons.FindAll(p => duplicatedSSN.Contains(p.SSN));. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Person> actualPersons = persons.Distinct().ToList();
List<Person> duplicatePersons = persons.Except(actualPersons).ToList();
```

Comment: This did not work since Distinct looks at all of the data. I just want to compare SSN and look for dupes on that one field.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the recommendation by @gcores above.

If you want to add a single object of the duplicated SSN back to the list of persons, then add the following line:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Person>> query = duplicated.GroupBy(d => d.SSN, d => d);

        foreach (IGrouping<string, Person> duplicateGroup in query)
        {
            persons.Add(duplicateGroup .First());
        }
```

My assumption here is that you may only want to remove duplicate values minus the original value that the duplicates derived from.

Answer (score 0):

well if you implement IComparable like so:

```
int IComparable<Person>.CompareTo(Person person)
{
    return this.SSN.CompareTo(person.SSN);
}
```

then a comparison like the following will work:

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < people.Count; i++)
{
    for (Int32 j = 1; j < items.Count; j++)
    {
        if (i != j && items[i] == items[j])
        {
            // duplicate
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Traverse the list and keep a Hashtable of SSN/count pairs.  Then enumerate your table and remove the items that match SSNs where SSN count > 0.

```
Dictionary<string, int> ssnTable = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach (Person person in persons)
{
   try
   {
      int count = ssnTable[person.SSN];
      count++;
      ssnTable[person.SSN] = count;
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
       ssnTable.Add(person.SSN, 1);
   }
}

// traverse ssnTable here and remove items where value of entry (item count) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `persons` have to be a `List<Person>`?  What if it were a `Dictionary<int, Person>`?

```
var persons = new Dictionary<int, Person>();

...

// For each person you want to add to the list:
var person = new Person
{
  ...
};

if (!persons.ContainsKey(person.SSN))
{
  persons.Add(person.SSN, person);
}

// If you absolutely, positively got to have a List:
using System.Linq;
List<Person> personsList = persons.Values.ToList();
```

If you are working with unique instances of `Person` (as opposed to different instances that might happen to have the same properties), you might get better performance with a [`HashSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).